# Cannot build hector_localization

Tags: ros, hector-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm trying to use pose estimation in the hector_localization package but I encounter problems during catkin_make.

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package geographic_msgs.

  Set geographic_msgs_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration
  file for geographic_msgs.  The file will have one of the following names:

    geographic_msgsConfig.cmake
    geographic_msgs-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  hector_localization/hector_pose_estimation_core/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)
```

Anybody got any solutions?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215611/cannot-build-hector_localization/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This means the `geographic_msgs` package is missing from your workspace. The easiest way to install is (assuming you're on indigo):

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-geographic-msgs
```

/edit: If you cannot install via package manager, you should try adding the a source version directly to your workspace. There is a "groovy" branch available: https://github.com/ros-geographic-info/geographic_info.git. The most simple option is to just copy the package into you workspace, the recommended approach would be using wstool however (see [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/64988/syntax-for-wstool-set/)).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-11**:
Hi there! I suspected that too. I'm using Groovy, but sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-geographic-msgs cannot be found. Any way else I can do?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-08-11**:
Yes, I updated the answer.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-08-11**:
Thanks! I got it. I need to create a rosbuild_ws and rosmake geographic_info and afterwards, put the same packages in catkin_ws and catkin_make again. ^^

**Comment by [Wafaay](https://answers.ros.org/users/3703/wafaay/) on 2017-03-18**:
Thank you ! ... I had the same issue ... I couldn't fix it using [geographic-info](https://github.com/ros-geographic-info/geographic_info) ... It only worked using the apt command above.